# Buy any X product for X amount?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I was trying to solve the problem But I could not figure it out.
I have `product` dictionary:

```
product = {
"shirt" : {
        "price" :300 ,
        "no_reqired_for_dis" : {"3": ["shirt","pents","tshirt","shorts"],"discount_price" : 250}},
"pents" : {
        "price" :200 ,
        "no_reqired_for_dis" : {"3": ["shirt","pents","tshirt","shorts"],"discount_price" : 250}}
"tshirt" : {
        "price" :150 ,
        "no_reqired_for_dis" : {"3": ["shirt","pents","tshirt","shorts"],"discount_price" : 250}}
"shorts" : {
        "price" :100 ,
        "no_reqired_for_dis" : {"3": ["shirt","pents","tshirt","shorts"],"discount_price" : 250}}
            }
```

What should be best approach to to find the total
discount criteria  if anyone who buys a minimum of  three products or a multiple of 3 they will get three item for 250?

for example if someone buy total 11 (shirt = 5,pants = 4, tshirt = 1, short = 1) products,then their total should be 250 * 3 + remaining item * lowest price product. Here remaining item should be lowest price of the product(here it should be shorts and tshirt).

I have done this:

```
total_payment = 0
total_product = {"shirt" : 5,"pents":4,"tshirt":1,"shorts" 1}
total_item = sum(total_product.values())
for key, value in total_product.items():
    min_no_required_for_discount = product[key]["no_required_for_dis"].keys()
    if total_item < int(min_no_required_for_discount[0]:
       total_payment += value * product[key]["price"]
    else:
       remaining_unit  = total_item % 3
       total_pair  = (total_item - remaining_unit) // 3
       total_payment += total_pair * 250
```

Now i am confuse in remaining_unit. how to calculate price for remaining_unit because remaining_unit must multiply with who has minimum price . in above example remaining_unit will be 2 and it will calculate price of shorts and tshirt

Comment: So basically you want to ignore the prices of all the items, except the `len(cart) % 3` least expensive (assuming `cart` is a list of items like `["shirt", "shirt", "shorts"]`) -- try putting together a sorted list of prices and then take into account only the ones you care about based on that information.

Comment: @alex - can you show us where you got stuck? and the initial effort that you've tried?

Comment: @entrez so basically what i want to try is calculating total amount so here i am trying to calculation max discount .

Comment: Hi, @alex, hope you find it's helpful.

Comment: hi Deniel i have just updated original post with initial effort .

Comment: Not sure how this statement will work: total_item = sum(product.values())         Because the product is a nested dictionary, right?!  Are you  sure you did not change the product dict. from original post?

Comment: Oh sorry it was typo i have just updated

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick template that might help you to start working on this problem:
[Notes: use set() to get the items difference quickly, and use print() statement to confirm each step is expected] Again, this is **NOT** a complete solution - but just offers a good template for you to start quickly.

```py
from pprint import pprint

lowest_price_items  = ['tshirt', 'shorts']
discount_price_items = ['shirt', 'pants']
discount_Set = set(discount_price_items)

cart = ['shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'pants', 'pants', 'pants', 'pants', 'tshirt', 'shorts']
cart_Set = set(cart)
low_price_goods =  cart_Set - discount_Set


pprint(product)

print(f' products: {product.keys()} ') #  first level of prod. dict.
print(product['shirt'].keys())         #  'price'  and 'no_requied_for_dis'

#       products   key1                key2
print(product['shirt']['no_reqired_for_dis']['discount_price'])  # 250
tshirt_price = product['tshirt']['price']
print(tshirt_price)

"""
total should be 250 * 3 + remaining item * lowest_price_products (tshirts, shorts) only
"""

total_items = len(cart)
print(total_items)

# modify this to calculate the final price.
if total_items > 3:
    final_price = 250 * total_items %3 + "remaining item * lowest_price_products" # select the lowest price items
```